# How to repeatedly fade in and out spans of a container element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm brand new to jQuery and trying to create an area of my website where testimonials can fade in and out one at a time. I can get the first testimonial to fade in, delay, and then fade out, but I can't get the next testimonial to repeat (and so on).

Also, how would I write the code so it would be a loop?

Here's my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/PTC3n/14/

```
<blockquote>
<span class="t1">Your service was amazing and your attention to detail was even better. We surely will hire you to do the job again!</span>
<span class="t2">This is another testimonial here telling how good the service was and how they'd like to hire us again.</span>
<span class="t3">And once more this is another testimonial here that will show how awesome we are.</span>
</blockquote>

$('.t1')
.hide()
.fadeIn(3000)
.delay(5000)
.fadeOut(3000);

$('.t2')
.hide();

$('.t3')
.hide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do this is have the JavaScript run independently from your markup.  First change I made was modifying your blockquote tag to have an Id attribute.

```
<blockquote id='testimonials'>    
    <span>Your service was amazing and your attention to detail was even better. We surely will hire you to do the job again!</span>
    <span>This is another testimonial here telling how good the service was and how they'd like to hire us again.</span>
    <span>And once more this is another testimonial here that will show how awesome we are.</span>
</blockquote>
```

Each span within our blockquote element is a different quote we want to display to the user, but we don't want to display them all at once. So I then applied a CSS rule to hide all spans contained within the element with the Id of testimonials.

```
#testimonials span
{
 display:none;
}
```

*This selector targets all SPAN elements contained within the element with the id of testimonials*

Great now all our span tags are hidden. But you might be asking yourself, why I removed all the class you were using for defining elements? Well, good question.  Going back to what I said at the beginning of the post, I wanted you're JavaScript to run independently from your markup. While we can't get true independence, we can be a little smarter with the following query selector in JavaScript.

```
var testimonials = $('#testimonials span');
```

This returns an array of three jQuery objects representing each of the span tags. Now we have an array we can iterate over to turn on and off.  What's good about this is you no longer have classes in your markup (T1, T2) that represent backed objects in JavaScript. You can freely add more span tags to the blockquote element and the fading in and out will work correctly. The solution uses annonomous function callbacks.  These are parameters you are seeing on the fadeIn and fadeOut lines. These functions are invoked once the animation is complete. In this case, after 1 second.

Below is the complete function and the jsFiddle is included at the bottom.

```
//get all testimonials
var testimonials = $('#testimonials span');
//set a starting index of 0
var index = 0;

//Start displaying testimonials
displayTestimonial();

function displayTestimonial()
{
    //Check to see if we need to reset back to the first index
    if(index + 1 > testimonials.length)
    {
        index=0;
    }

    //Display a testmonial and when testimonial is complete fade it out
    $(testimonials[index]).fadeIn(1000, function()
    {
        //Fade testimonial out and when complete increment the current span index and 
        $(testimonials[index]).fadeOut(1000, function() 
         {
             index++;
             //Have the function call itself                                 
             displayTestimonial();
         });
    });
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J9Bys/)

Comment: That was great! I'll study it today to better understand it. Thanks.

Comment: cgatian,  how do I write it so it fades in but stays static for a few seconds and then fades out. Right now, it fades in and out. Thanks.

Comment: This does not seem to be compatible with Chrome. There is no graceful fade-in. It works nicely in FFox, though.

Comment: I wrote this in Chrome